# How to resolve this _tkinter.TclError problem?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I want to make video downloader using tkinter in python.
This is the code:

```
from  tkinter import *
from  tkinter import filedialog
from  pytube import YouTube
from tkinter.ttk import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry("500*500+350+100")
window.title("Youtube Downloader")
window.resizable(False,False)
```

and it says error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\baraa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\folder\baraa.py", line 6, in <module>
    window.geometry("500*500+350+100")
  File "C:\Users\baraa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2044, in wm_geometry
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'geometry', self._w, newGeometry)
_tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "500*500+350+100"
```

Comment: Well, in your own words, what do you expect `window.geometry("500*500+350+100")` to mean? How did you decide on which `*` and `+` symbols to use in what places? What does the documentation say about how the string should look? Do you see a discrepancy?

Comment: Here's some documentation on [geometry strings](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/geometry.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the error:

```
bad geometry specifier "500500+350+100"
```

There's a wrong format in your geometry.

Try this:

```
# tkinter window 
window.geometry('500x500 + 350 + 100')
```

Comment: i tried but nothing

Comment: What's the error now ?

Comment: If you try this :   window.geometry('200x150')   , what's happen ?

Comment: it print nothing

Comment: @BaraaJawish you need to type `window.mainloop()` at the end